# Transform grammar into LL(1)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ll-grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
START -> STM $
STM -> VAR = EXPR
STM -> EXPR
EXPR -> VAR
VAR -> id
VAR -> * EXPR
```

With this `first`and `follow` sets:

```
          First set     Follow set
START       id, *       $
STM         id, *       $
EXPR        id, *       $, =
VAR         id, *       $, =
```

I've created the parsing table that follows:

```
                $           =           id              *               $
START                           START → STM $        START → STM $
STM                             STM → VAR = EXPR    STM → VAR = EXPR
                                STM → EXPR          STM → EXPR
EXPR                            EXPR → VAR          EXPR → VAR
VAR                             VAR → id            VAR → id
                                VAR → * EXPR        VAR → * EXPR
```

From here I can see that this is not `LL(1)`.

How can I modify this grammar so that it becomes `LL(1)`?

Comment: There's no systematic way to do it. You need to go through all the various ways of transforming grammars discussed in pretty much any compilers textbook. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10616824/3438854) has a fairly good overview.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about what sorts of strings can be generated by this particular grammar, it's all the strings of one of the following forms:

```
 ***....**id
 ***....**id = ***...**id
```

With this in mind, you can design an LL(1) grammar for this language by essentially building a new grammar for the language from scratch. Here's one way to do this:

> Start → Statement $
>
> Statement → StarredID OptExpr
>
> StarredID → * StarredID | id
>
> OptExpr → ε | = StarredID

Here, the FIRST sets are given as follows:

- FIRST(Start) = {*, id}
- FIRST(Statement) = {*, id}
- FIRST(StarredID) = {*, id}
- FIRST(OptExpr) = {ε, *, id}
- FOLLOW(Statement) = {$}
- FOLLOW(StarredID) = {=, $}
- FOLLOW(OptExpr) = {$}

The parse table is then shown here:

```
                  *                 | id                | =             $
 ---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------
 Start          | Statement$        | Statement$        |             |
 Statement      | StarredID OptExpr | StarredID OptExpr |             |
 StarredID      | * StarredID       | id                |             |
 OptExpr        |                   |                   | = StarredID | epsilon
```

So this grammar is LL(1).